# How to sync multiple feature branches with master in git

Tags: git, github, branching-and-merging

My Scenario is this :
From master branch to feature branch1 , add changes to branch1 then create another branch from branch1 called branch2, then add changes to branch2.

If there are then pending changes to the master branch , what's the best approach to sync all branches with the master branch

`Branch creation as follows Master to F1 then F1 to  F2`

Comment: What I'd try to do is Merge changes from master into branch2 and merge branch2 into branch 1 .would this be the most efficient approach ?

Answer (score 1):

You could rebase `branch2` on top of `master` using `--update-refs` which is a *newish* option that will also update references that are setup in the *path* to `branch2`, so should move the position of `branch1` .

```
git checkout branch2
git rebase --update-refs master
```

The kind of step by step way would be:

```
git checkout branch1
git branch temp # let's set a temporary marker before I move it
git rebase master
# now time to rebase branch2
git rebase --onto branch1 temp branch2
# remove the temporary branch if things went fine
git branch -D temp
```

The last rebase will rebase commits in the `temp..branch2` range on top of `branch1`